# VECM Impulse Response Function: Interpretation of Results

Tags: time-series, correlation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

I estimated a VECM and generated Generalised Impulse Response Functions based on Johansen Cointegration.

Below is an output of two response variables to a shock in GDP. My issue is, I have strong reason to believe the two variables should be converging in the long run as they are highly correlated and since they are cointegrated when tested together in isolation. If this were the case, shouldn't these two variables' trends be converging in the graph below, rather than having a gap between them? What does this gap imply?

Also, the impulse variable is in logs and the response variable is in level percentage changes; how do I interpret the magnitude (y-axis) of the trend? Thanks for the help!

[image: VECM IRF]